# Should I provide structured data for the related products on a single product page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, ecommerce

In a single product page, should I provide Schema.org structured data for the related products, too?

As an example, [this is a page of my ecommerce](https://www.gioielleriacunsolo.com/negozio/emporio-armani-orologio-ar1865/). As you can see, there are 5 `Product` items in the page. One for the product, and 4 for the related products. Should I remove (or change) them?

Comment: In which way are the products related?

Comment: What are you hoping to get out of adding schema?  It doesn't help with rankings and Google doesn't show special search results for just any schema.  It has a list of schema that it actually uses: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery   If you have to ask if you should use schema the answer is probably "No".

Comment: There's no obvious benefit to it at the moment, so maybe it's best to keep things simple. Saying that, if lots of people mark it up, Google may decide it is of use to them.

Comment: Hi Mario, do you feel as if I answered your question completely? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate on what else you need to know so the community can provide you with further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to provide Schema information for related products. Adding Schema information to the main product of each page is enough to make you eligible for [product rich snippets in Google Search](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product).

What will happen is that Google's crawler will automatically follow the links to your related products and index their Schema data from their own main pages.

Comment: It's obviously logical to include structured data for the product to which the page relates, however is there likely to be any penalty if structured data is also provided for the products in a 'related products' box listing on the same page? If structured data was to be included for the related products then that data would be repeated on other product pages. Also the SD for related products would not be matching on-page content.

Comment: @NickW What kind of structured data are you considering using on related products, that adds additional information beyond what the crawler would get by visiting the related product's own web page?